# Filter out objects from one array of objects based on the contents of another array of objects

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm a bit stuck and was hoping someone can help me. What i would like to do is: Bookings has only one timeslot that is in use. I would like to have a newTimeslots array with only Timeslot 2.

```
var bookings : [Booking] = [Booking(bookingType: "PICKUP", date: "JAN6", timeSlotID: 1),]

var timeSlots : [TimeSlot] = [TimeSlot(name: "Timeslot 1", id: 1),TimeSlot(name: "Timeslot 2", id: 2)]

var newTimeslots : [TimeSlot] = []
```

Comment: Please don't spam tags. The Xcode tag should only be used for questions regarding the IDE itself. The Swift version tags should only be used for questions around specific changes in a version. Also, your question is about Swift itself, arrays have nothing to do with iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` to only keep the elements of `timeSlots` whose ID does not match any of the IDs in `bookings`.

```
let emptyTimeSlots = timeSlots.filter { timeSlot in !bookings.contains(where: {$0.timeSlotID == timeSlot.id }) }
```